# Creating a Junction in C# with variables

Tags: c#, variables, junction

I am writing a program that will link two directories together.  The idea is that someone with a game save file can sync with a directory in their Dropbox account.  The program checks to see if Dropbox is installed and asks the user to select the two directories that he/she wishes to sync together.  The game directory is stored in textBox_Game.Text and chosen Dropbox folder in textBox_DB.Text.

```
private void button_link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strCmdText;
            string sourceDir = textBox_Game.Text;
            string destinationDir = textBox_DB.Text;

            strCmdText = "/c MKLINK /J C:\Dest C:\Source";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        }
    }
```

I am currently doing a lot of programs in C++ so I'm familiar with the concept of outputting different variables and strings on a single line... however this is not c++... I didn't expect it to work but I tried `strCmdText = "/c MKLINK /J " >> destinationDir >> " " >> sourceDir;` just in case it would recommend something.

Obviously this is me attempting to use the command line. Also, if there is a way to do this without the need of installing libraries that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `strCmdText = "/c MKLINK /J C:\Dest C:\Source";` with:

```
strCmdText = "/c MKLINK /J " + destinationDir + " " + sourceDir;
```